# Angular 5 + Material Design: <mat-select> how to set the default value?

Tags: mongodb, typescript, material-design, angular-material2, angular5

```
 <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select [formControl]="form.controls['defaultCategory']" [(ngModel)]="resource.categoryName" >
        <mat-option *ngFor="let category of categories | async" [value]="category._id" >
          {{ category.name }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

I tried many things. The docs, some bug-reports on github still not solve my Problem.

I only want do preset a default value...

The default value is stored a variable named: resource.categoryName. The options comes from a collection from mongodb and these are stored in categories[].

[This picture shows the closed mat-select (no default value shown, but it should...)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gadvw.png)

[opened mat-select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm7EI.png)

[Here is my .ts. The important line is "`this.resource.categoryName = this.subdoc['name'];`". There i set the "resource.categoryName. **If i try to console.log(this.resource.categoryName), then i get the name of the category...**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB9SQ.png)

*Creating a variable in the .ts and be sure its a string. After that declare the variable with the ID of the default Category. (in my case it only worked with the ID, not with the simple name) - Thanks to Simeon, Hamid and other Threads about this problem.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your component file but the problem might be that your resource.categoryName doesn't have a value set on initialization of the component. Try setting it manually in your *.component.ts file.

Comment: I added a picture of my .ts where i set the value. (if you need more infos, let me know)

Comment: I agree with Simeon. If `resource.categoryName` has a value or you initialize a value to `resource.categoryName` in your component.ts, it will work magically.

Comment: Yeah my problem was I delcared the name of the category. I have to declare the ID to the "defaultSelectedVariable"